# Find discrete convolution of $f$.

Tags: functional-analysis, convolution

I am trying to understand convolution and I am stuck in this particular problem in which I have to find the discrete convolution of $f[x] = [1,2,1,0,1,0-1,-2]$ with the signal $g[x] = [1, 1, -1,-1]$. I have no idea  on how to use the following formula
$$ f * g[m] = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} f[n]g[m-n]
$$
in order to find the discrete convolution of $f$. Can anyone help me?

Comment: there is no comma betrween 0 and -1 in the input array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the sequence $f(x)$ exists from $0$ to $7$, and $g(x)$ exists from $0$ to $3$,

$f*g(n) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} f(m)g(n-m) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} g(m)f(n-m)$.

$f*g(n)= \sum_{m=0}^{3} g(m)f(n-m)$.

$f*g(0)= \sum_{m=0}^{3} g(m)f(0-m) = g(0)f(0) = 1$

$f*g(1)= \sum_{m=0}^{3} g(m)f(1-m) = g(0)f(1)+g(1)f(0) = 3$, and so on.

This is if you go by formula. If the 2 sequences are less in length, then there is a matrix method to solve easily.
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I have issues understanding, how you proceed after $f*g(7)$? Isn't $n=7$? Because, in the end you get a sequence of length $7$.

Comment: From the convolution property $f*g(n)$ exists for $n=0$ to $n=11$. So, $f*g(7)=\sum_{m=0}^{3}g(m)f(7-m)=g(0)f(7)+g(1)f(6)+g(2)f(5)+g(3)f(4)$

Comment: But for $f * g(8) = \sum_{m=0}^{3} g(m)f(8-m) = g(0)f(8) + \dots + g(3)f(5)$ I do not have any function value for $f(8)$, how would I compute it? I do not really understand the matrix method. Additionally, which convolution property are you refering to when you say $f*g(n)$ exists for $n = 0$ to $n = 11$?

Comment: Since $f(8)$ doesn't exist, it should be zero. And coming to matrix method, write elements of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in the fashion shown in the picture. Multiply first element of $g(x)$ with whole $f(x)$ and so on. Add the elements across the diagonal as indicated by lines. Finally you get the convolution output sequence

Comment: Tell me, if $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are sequences of lengths $L$ and $M$ respectively, what will be the length of sequence $f*g(n)$?. If you know this, you can find why  $f*g(n)$ exists only for values of $n=0$ to $n=11$ and will be zero for other values of $n$.

Comment: I do not know. Are there any resources you can point me to where I can read about the properties of discrete convolution?

Comment: $f*g(n)$ will be of length $L+M-1$. You can use this book 'Signals and Systems' by Oppenheim as a resource.